# previous_posts_link not working in WordPress pagination

Tags: wp-query, pagination

I'm using a custom query in my front page to show some posts from a category. it ll be selected by the admin from backend(using redux framework to do that). Now when I click older entries (`next_posts_link`) it's working fine & go to the next page. but I don't see newer entries (`previous_posts_link`) so I can get back to the first page or previous page again.here is my snippet:

```
<ul class="recipe-list">
    <?php
        $home_rcp= $redux_imd['home_rcp'];

        // Define custom query parameters
        $rcpquery_args = array(
        'cat' => $home_rcp,
        'posts_per_page' => 4
        );

        // Get current page and append to custom query parameters array
        $rcpquery_args['paged'] = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : 1;

        // Instantiate custom query
        $rcpquery =  new WP_Query( $rcpquery_args );

        // Pagination fix
        $temp_query = $wp_query;
        $wp_query   = NULL;
        $wp_query   = $rcpquery;

        while($rcpquery->have_posts()) : $rcpquery->the_post();
    ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('recipe-thumb'); ?>
        <div class="caption">
            <div class="blur"></div>
            <div class="caption-text">
                <div class="post-title">
                    <h5><?php the_title() ?></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="recipe-home-meta">
                    <p>Posted  on <?php the_time('Y/m/d'); ?> By <?php the_author(); ?></p>
                </div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">SEE THIS RECIPE</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    <div id="pagination">
    <?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $rcpquery->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;', $rcpquery->max_num_pages); ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    // Reset main query object
    $wp_query = NULL;
    $wp_query = $temp_query;
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you mean index.php, if so, why are you using a custom query then

Comment: Also, if it is the home page, why are you using `page` and not `paged`. `page` is only used for static front pages and single post pages

Comment: no in Front page, I have already used another query in this page.

Comment: Then please post the correct info in your question.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have edited the post.